# DAX measure for Slicer based on dates period and returns dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a Date table and a FactSales table and their relationship is Date[date] and FactSales[Date]. I have a measure that sum sales e.g Total sales = SUM(FactSales[sales]). I have a table called Relation.

```
_______________________________________________________________________
Match                    | TypeID | Type           | No  |Datepartname |
________________________________________________________________________
DEFAULT - Year on Year   | 1      |Userelationship | NA  | NA          |
Previous 1 Week          | 3      | Dateadd        | 1   | Week        |
Previous 2 Week          | 3      | Dateadd        | 2   | Week        |
Previous 3 Week          | 3      | Dateadd        | 3   | Week        |
Previous 12 Week         | 3      | Dateadd        | 12  | Week        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This Relation[Match] column will be used as a slicer that will filter through the date table to get the Total Sales based on what is selected.

I am struggling in making this work by using the DAX below:
First I need to identify the current date by using the variable _maxDate

```
measure = 
Var _maxDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( Date[Dates] ), ALLSELECTED ( Date ) )   --- current's date
var _selection = SELECTEDVALUE(Relation[Match] )
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
        _selection = "DEFAULT - Year on Year", "DEFAULT - Year on Year",
        _selection = "Previous 1 Week", DATEADD(Date[Dates],-7,DAY),
        _selection = "Previous 2 Week”, DATEADD(Date[Dates],-14,DAY),
        _selection = "Previous 3 Week", DATEADD(Date[Dates],-21,DAY),
        _selection = "Previous 12 Week", DATEADD(Date[Dates],-84,DAY),
        BLANK()
)
```

My Dax return error.

Expected outcome:

Whenever, Previous 1 week is selected on the slicer, it should return the previous week date and when Previous 2 week is selected, it should return 2 weeks ago date and so on.
If this is achieved, then the measure should automatically be computed based on what is selected on the slicer.